# Passar Valores pela Stream / bloc

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um arquivo login_bloc.dart e dentro do mesmo tenho a seguinte situação.

```
final usuario = BehaviorSubject<String>();

 usuario.sink.add(user.email);
```

e no arquivo home_screen.dart, tenho a seguinte situação.

```
final _loginBloc = LoginBlock();
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: _loginBloc.usuario,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(_loginBloc.usuario);
        print(snapshot.data);
```

O que acontece é que:

- O `print(_loginBloc.usuario)` me retorna -> `Instance of 'BehaviorSubject<String>'`
- O `print(snapshot.data)` me retorna -> `null`.

A pergunta é, como eu trago meu "user.email" pra outro aquivo?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa acrescentar algumas coisas a mais no seu BLoC, siga as modificações abaixo...

Em login_bloc.dart

```
  final BehaviorSubject<String> _usuario = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("");
  Stream<String> get outUsuario  => _usuario .stream;
  Sink<String> get inUsuario  => _usuario .sink;

  inUsuario.add(user.email);
```

Em home_screen.dart

```
final _loginBloc = LoginBlock();
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: _loginBloc.outUsuario,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) /* Se não tiver nenhuma informação no BLoC retorna um Container vazio, senão executa o resto do código*/
          return Container()

        return Text(snapshot.data);
       });
 }
```

**Explicação**

O `StreamBuilder` como o próprio nome diz precisa receber em seu parâmetro `stream` uma Stream e você estava passando para ele o `BehaviorSubject` que serve, a grosso modo, como um controller...

Com BLoC, na maior parte do tempo, você irá trabalhar em cima das propriedades `Sink` e `Stream` dos respectivos `BehaviorSubject`.

**Observação**

Se com as mudanças que sugeri acima não funcionar, você precisa rever a lógica que está utilizando para chamar seu BLoC, pois se está alimentando o BLoC em outra lugar, ao fazer a chamada `final _loginBloc = LoginBlock();` você irá pegar um BLoC novo, ou seja, sem os dados que inseriu no outro lugar.

Para acessar os dados do BLoC que foram inseridos fora da sua classe `home_screen`, você precisa colocar seu BlocProvider na sua árvore principal de Widgets  dessa maneira

```
BlocProvider(
      blocs: [ 
        Bloc((i) => LoginBlock()), 
      ],
      child: PaginaInicial()
    );
```

E depois para acessá-lo na sua `home_screen`, ao invés disso

```
final _loginBloc = LoginBlock();
```

Faça assim

```
final _loginBloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<LoginBlock>();
```

*Você pode dar uma olhada em meu projeto do GitHub [EquipmentMaintenance](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/EquipmentMaintenance), onde utilizo BLoC.*

Comment: Olá Matheus, fiz como sugeriu, porém percebi que quando declaro o .seeded(" "); A home_screen.dart só recebe o espaço em branco. Por exemplo, se eu declarar .seeded("teste"), mesmo declarado o inUsuario.add(user.email) a  home_screen.dart ainda não está recebendo esse parâmetro. Ai sem o seeded, a home_screen.dart, só recebe null, se tiver mais alguma sugestão. De qualquer maneira muito obrigado, abriu minha mente, principalmente com a explicação.

Comment: @GatoPreto de uma olhada novamente em minha resposta, eu havia esquecido de modificar algumas coisas! O `seeded("")` não é necessário, você pode fazer assim `BehaviorSubject<String>()` apenas.